# How do you read auth header with Apollo Server 2.0 beta

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

With Apollo Server 1.x one could use Express middleware to read the auth header and modify the context object. Is there a way to do this with Apollo Server 2 beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing about Apollo Server 2 is that you can create a context handler when you initialize the server.

You could try something like the following:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    const [bearer, token] = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')
    const user = getUserByToken(token)
    return { user }
  }
})
```

And now you have the `user` inside the context object provided to each resolver.